# User info won't show in my profile page and in localstorage only the refreshtoken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

When i login in my website it is working, but the user in the navbar is not showing and when i go to my userprofile the userinfo is also not showing. When i got to storage>localstorage only the refreshtoken is being shown and not the details like email, username and etc..

Here is my profile.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import '../bootstrap.min.css'
import {Tabs, Tab, Card, Col, Button, ListGroup, Row} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from './Product'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listProducts } from '../Actions/productActions';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function Profile() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  // const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const userLogin = useSelector(state=>state.userLogin)
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;


  
  
  const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
  const { error, loading, products } = productList
  useEffect(() =>{
    dispatch(listProducts())
  }, [])
    return(
        <div>
            <div style={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"space",margin:"18px 0px"}}>
                <div>
                    <img style={{width:"160px",height:"160px",borderRadius:"80px"}} src="https://i.imgur.com/am2WI0k.png"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Username: {userInfo.name}</h2>
                    <h4>Email: {userInfo.email}</h4>
                     <br/><h5>"CAPTION HERE TRY KO LAGYAN"</h5>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>   
                </div>  
            </div>
              <Tabs
                defaultActiveKey="profile"
                id="fill-tab-example"
                className="mb-3"
                fill
              >
              <Tab eventKey="works" title="Works">
                <Col>
                <Row>
            {products.map(product => (
                <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                    <Product product ={product} />
                </Col>
            ))}
        </Row>
                </Col>
              </Tab>
              <Tab eventKey="Personal Info" title="Personal Info">
                <ListGroup variant="flush">
                  <ListGroup.Item>Twitter: @Unnamed-san</ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>Email: U_san@yahoo.com</ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>Contact Number: 09448273844</ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
              </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Profile;
```

Here is my userActions.js

```
import { USER_LOGIN_FAIL,USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,USER_LOGOUT,USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,USER_REGISTER_FAIL,USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,USER_REGISTER_REQUEST, } from '../Constants/userConstants';
import axios from 'axios';

export const login = (email,password)=> async(dispatch)=>{



   try{
       dispatch({
           type:USER_LOGIN_REQUEST
       })

       const config ={
           headers:{
               'Content-type':'application/json'
           }
       }

       const {data}= await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/',
       
       {'username':email,'password':password},config
       
       
       )

       dispatch({
           type:USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
           payload:data
       })

       localStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify(data))



   }

   catch(error){
    dispatch({
        type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.detail
            ? error.response.data.detail
            : error.message,
      });
   }

}


export const register =(name,email,password)=> async(dispatch)=>{
    try{

       dispatch({
           type:USER_REGISTER_REQUEST
       })

       const config = {
           headers:{
               'Content-type':'application/json'
           }
       }

       const {data}= await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/register/',
       
       
       {'name':name,'email':email,'password':password },config )

       dispatch({
           type:USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
           payload:data
       })
       dispatch({
           type:USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
           payload:data
       })

       localStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify(data))

    }
    catch(error){

       dispatch({
           type:USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
           payload:error.response && error.response.data.detail
           ? error.response.data.detail
           :error.message,
       })

    }
}









export const logout = () => (dispatch) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('userInfo')
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOGOUT })
 
}
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated,IsAdminUser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view,permission_classes
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from .serializer import ChangePasswordSerializer,UpdateUserSerializer,UserSerializer,UserSerializerWithToken
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import generics
# Create your views here.


@api_view(['GET'])
def getRoutes(request):
    return Response('Hello')


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def validate(self,attrs):
        data=super().validate(attrs)
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(self.user).data
        for k,v in serializer.items():
            data[k]=v
    

        return data

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class=MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
    
        


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def  getUserProfiles(request):
    user=request.user
    serializer=UserSerializer(user,many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def  getUsers(request):
    user=User.objects.all()
    serializer=UserSerializer(user,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


# register the new users

@api_view(['POST'])
def registerUser(request):
    data=request.data
    print(data)
    try:

        user=User.objects.create(
            first_name=data['name'],
            username=data['email'],
            email=data['email'],
            password=make_password(data['password'])
        )
        serializer=UserSerializerWithToken(user,many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except:
        message={'details':'USER WITH THIS EMAIL ALREADY EXIST'}
        return Response(message,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    

    
    

class ChangePasswordView(generics.UpdateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer

class UpdateProfileView(generics.UpdateAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UpdateUserSerializer
```

Serializer.py

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator




# class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
#     class Meta:
#         model=User
#         fields=['id','username','email']
        
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name=serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    _id=serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin=serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['id','_id','username','email','name','isAdmin']

    def get_name(self,obj):
        name=obj.first_name
        if name=="":
            name=obj.email
        return name
    
    def get__id(self,obj):
        return obj.id

    def get_isAdmin(self,obj):
        return obj.is_staff


class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token=serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['id','_id','username','email','name','isAdmin','token']
    
    def get_token(self,obj):
        token=RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)


class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    old_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('old_password', 'password', 'password2')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})

        return attrs

    def validate_old_password(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.check_password(value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"old_password": "Old password is not correct"})
        return value

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()

        return instance


class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'first_name': {'required': True},
            'last_name': {'required': True},
        }

    def validate_email(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk).filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"email": "This email is already in use."})
        return value

    def validate_username(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk).filter(username=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"username": "This username is already in use."})
        return value

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user

        if user.pk != instance.pk:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"authorize": "You dont have permission for this user."})

        instance.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
        instance.last_name = validated_data['last_name']
        instance.email = validated_data['email']
        instance.username = validated_data['username']

        instance.save()

        return instance
```

## I followed everthing on my other code(because the userinfo is showing there) but it is still not working i don't know why.

Comment: ugh - big shouty bold text at the end of the question - why?

Comment: stackoverflow said it is needed